# Django: form.is_valid() error, but only after "if request.method == 'POST'"?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I `print(formexam)` BEFORE the `if request.method == 'POST'`, it shows the appropriately filled out form items (the exam was created earlier, now I'm just updating it to make changes as desired).

However, when I `print(formexam)` AFTER `if request.method == 'POST'`, it shows the form fields (at least several of them, I didn't look at every single one) to be empty.  What makes that happen?

(In my example code below, I am printing the errors instead of the form.)

Also, a very very similar `views.py` function (`changeExam`, bottom of this post) works just fine.

Thank you!

---

**views.py**

```
def updateExam(request, pk):
    exam = Exam.objects.get(id=pk)

    formod = form_od.ODForm(instance=exam.od)
    formos = form_os.OSForm(instance=exam.os)
    formexam = ExamForm(instance=exam)
    print(f'The errors are: {formexam.errors}')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formexam = ExamForm(request.POST, instance=exam)
        print(f'The errors are: {formexam.errors}')
        formod = form_od.ODForm(request.POST, instance=exam.od)
        formos = form_os.OSForm(request.POST, instance=exam.os)

        if formod.is_valid() and formos.is_valid():
            print("these are valid")
            if formexam.is_valid():
                print("so is this one.")

                #save exam
                instance = formexam.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

                #save OD
                instance = formod.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

                #save OS
                instance = formos.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

             else:
                print("Exam form not valid.")

                #save OD
                instance = formod.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

                #save OS
                instance = formos.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

        else:
            print("No forms are valid.")


    context = {
        'formod': formod,
        'formos': formos,
        'formexam': formexam,
        'exam': exam,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/form_exam_update.html', context)
```

**Results of hitting submit button:**

```
The errors are: 
The errors are: <ul class="errorlist"><li>doctor<ul class="errorlist">.<li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>examtype<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
these are valid
Exam form not valid.
```

However, this very similar one works:
**views.py**

```
def changeExam(request, pk):
    exam = Exam.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = ExamForm(instance=exam)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExamForm(request.POST, instance=exam)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
            form.save()
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/form_exam.html', context)def
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

On **changeExam**, the resultant HTML page (form_exam.html) has `<form>` tags with all of the fields within the `<form>` tags.  Therefore, no error.

On **updateExam**, it's a larger page (form_exam_update.html) using Django template tags to include things in different sections, and I realized a few of the fields (e.g. doctor, examtype) were outside of the `<form>` tags.

I updated the HTML code so that all corresponding fields were within the `<form>` tags, and it now works as desired!